# Unable to connect to Jupyter notebook on AWS

Tags: windows-10, ssh, putty, amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

I have an EC2 t2-small Ubuntu instance running on AWS. I connect to this instance from a windows PC using putty.

In the all important Tunnels tab I have the source port as 8000 and destination as my AWS `instance:8888` which is where Jupyter note book Starts. I can see Jupyter notebook has started as it gives a message The Jupyter notebook is running at `http://localhost:8888/?token=XXXX`

However, when I open a browser session on my PC ad type in `http://localhost:8888`, I get an error message Site cannot be reached. Same with https same with 127.0.0.1 same with using 8000 instead of 8888.

Comment: The Jupyter Notebook is running on your AWS virtual machine and not on your local machine. From the perspective of your virtual machine, the notebook is running on `localhost` (= 127.0.0.1). I you try to access `localhost` via the webbrowser on your local machine, you are trying to access content on your local machine (and not on the AWS VM). You need an IP address or domain of your AWS VM

Comment: I entered the following command on AWS window: jupyter notebook --ip = * This then started Jupyter notebook and gave a messsage clearing invalid/expired login cookie username-localhost-8000. After that I was able to access Jupyter from client(local PC) using http://localhost:8000. Not sure of the explanation